# If a and b are numbers such that (a+8)(b-8)=0, what is the smallest possible value of a^2 + b^2?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is my first question on StackExchange.

I am studying for the SAT and came across this problem in a practice test:

If a and b are numbers such that $(a+8)(b-8)=0$, what is the smallest possible value of $a^2 + b^2$ ?

(A) $0$
(B) $8$
(C) $16$
(D) $64$
(E) $128$

The correct answer is D; however, the test wasn't from the OSSG, so an online explanation isn't available. Could you provide an explanation of the solution?

Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisJWelly the reason I didn't approve the edit was because I didn't know what would happen with the <br> tags, and apparently my concern was justified.

Comment: @MattSamuel I'm sorry! The options were side-by-side without the br tags in my preview. I did not expect this to happen either.

Comment: @ChrisJWelly In general I've found that using HTML isn't necessary here (though I think it works, the problem was that it was inside math mode). You can do linebreaks by putting in a blank line.

Comment: @ChrisJWelly (But not in math mode.)

Comment: @MattSamuel I see. I would say that I am still an amateur in formatting, and moreover, I am browsing from my mobile phone. There is much for me to learn. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the equation to be true, one of the factors of the first equation must equal $0$. For the sake of simplicity, let's say $a=-8$ so that our first factor is equal to $0$.

Now, $b$ can equal any value since $a$'s factor is $0$. From our second equation, we want to minimize $b^2$.

Clearly $b$ is $0$ since the minimum of $f(b)=b^2$ is $0$.

If $a$ was $-8$ and $b$ was $0$, $(-8)^2+0^2=64$. Option $D $ is correct.

Comment: "By convention" doesn't seem to be the right choice of words.

Comment: Agreed and fixed.

Answer (score 4):

For the product to equal $0$, one of the terms has to be $0$. The only way this can happen is if either $a=-8$ or $b=8$, so the answer is at least $64$. But the minimum is also at most 64 because we can just let the other one be $0$ to make the result as small as possible.

Comment: I can see it is at least 64, But what if I pick $a=100$ and $b=8$? The equation is met, but $a^2+b^2$ is certainly more than 64

Comment: @imranfat Yes but the goal is to make it small, so you wouldn't want to pick $a=100$. Instead you'd pick $a=0$. You have that freedom.

Comment: @imranfat You are looking for the smallest possible value of $a^2+b^2$.

Comment: @matt samuel. Yes, that is true, that is why I didn't get "but it is also at most 64" part. The minimum is 64, there is no "at most"

Comment: @imranfat When I say "it" I mean "the answer" which is the minimum. I'll edit it to make it clearer.

Comment: @imranfat I realize there's another possible interpretation to your question with respect to why I would say that the minimum is "at most" anything. That's really because I'm saying "$c=d$ because $c\leq d$ and $c\geq d$."

Comment: That makes sense...